# Accessing user attributes using UserAccessor

Tags: s4sdk

The class com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.user.UserAccessor allows to me to retrieve the current user and it's attributes.

For example:

```
    Optional<UserAttribute> optionalfirstName = user.getAttribute("firstname"); 
    UserAttribute ua = optionalfirstName.get();
```

Once I have retrieved the UserAttribute, it has two properites "Name" and "Value". However there is no method available to get the Value. How can I access the value?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the SAP CP environment you are using, the UserAttribute is an instance of:

- `SimpleUserAttribute<String>` on Neo
- `CollectionUserAttribute<String>` on Cloud Foundry

You can access the respective values by type-casting to the required instance:

```
if( ua instanceof SimpleUserAttribute ) {
    String value = (String) ((SimpleUserAttribute<?>)ua).getValue();
}
else if ( ua instanceof CollectionUserAttribute ) {
    Collection<?> values = ((CollectionUserAttribute<?>)ua).getValues();
}
```

**Note:** We plan to simplify this in future releases of the SDK so that `StringUserAttribute` and `StringCollectionUserAttribute` instances are returned for more convenient consumption.