# unable to define idp attribute in xs-security.json and use it in approuter

Tags: sap-cloud-foundry

Defining attributes and referencing them in role-templates works, but how can they be defined as static/saml attribute in xs-secutity.json? Application roles from xs-security can be edited in SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit, but not section ATTRIBUTES! What are the names/values in xs-security to provide this information? Otherwise source of the attribute is always "Unrestricted" and values "empty".

Solution from [Capture IDP User attributes in SAP cloud foundry app via SDK UserAccesor API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005822/capture-idp-user-attributes-in-sap-cloud-foundry-app-via-sdk-useraccesor-api) works only for roles created in cockpit.

Maybe there's a working example somewhere i haven't found? How is an exposed attribute then used in extended approuter?

Comment: did you ever solve this? Stuck at the same place